# contruct called from another class in a non hierarchical returns fatal error

Tags: php, oop

Why do I get an error while trying to invoke unrelated contructor?

```
class Employee
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        echo "<p>Employee construct called!!</p>";
    }
}

class Manager
{
    function __construct()
    {
        Employee::__construct();
        echo "<p> Manager Construct Called! </p>";
    }
}
```

Works fine when I invoke it in the child class

```
class Manager extends Employee
```

error:

```
Fatal error: Non-static method Employee::__construct() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in..
```

Comment: you just need to call the class, the construct is fired automatically ie `$employee = new Employee();`

Comment: Don't use the name of the class, use the keyword `parent::__construct()` instead.

Comment: @watcher its not the parent ...

Comment: Try `new Employee()` instead. Also read about [scope resolution operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) before playing with it

Comment: `class Manager extends Employee {` and `parent::__construct();`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I am trying to call the Employee construct in a non related class, I know it works in a hierarchical relation, how can you call a construct of an unrelated class ?

Comment: See RahilWazir and cmorrissey...

Comment: You know you should never do echo anything from constructors, they're meant to initialize the state

Comment: @djay You do realise they are just examples?

Comment: @maximl337 You should be doing it [like this](http://3v4l.org/QUgHe).

Comment: @vascowhite ah I see and get it now. can you post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the unrelated class using its constructor as usual. Like this:-

```
class Employee
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        echo "<p>Employee construct called!!</p>\n";
    }
}

class Manager
{

    protected $employee;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->employee = new Employee();
        echo "<p>Manager Construct Called! </p>\n";
    }
}

new Manager();
```

That is the simple way, but it is much better practice to pass the employee to the constructor as a dependency:-

```
class Employee
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        echo "<p>Employee construct called!!</p>\n";
    }
}

class Manager
{

    protected $employee;

    function __construct(Employee $employee)
    {
        $this->employee = $employee;
        echo "<p>Manager Construct Called! </p>\n";
    }
}

$manager = new Manager(new Employee());
```

But don't worry about it too much if you don't understand that just now.

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/QUgHe).